# Need to Figure Out CSS Selector For Video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to add a `cursor: pointer` to a video, but it's set up in jQuery (for a poster image and defer autoplay.) It works in the Inspector (the video shows under selector: "element".) I can add `cursor: pointer` to the video there, but cannot figure out what CSS selector to use.

I tried:

- styling the video tag, the iframe tag (both in css and directly in the jquery),
- using element queries in css with the [ ] brackets,
- styling the parent div, the other divs, etc.

What selector should I be using based on this?

This is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.vidposter').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var videoSRC = element.attr('data-videoSRC');
    var iframe = '<iframe width="570" height="321" src="' + videoSRC + '"></iframe>';
    element.html(iframe);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vidposter" data-videoSRC="http://thesite.com/media/video.mp4" autoplay="true">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/570x321/" style="cursor:pointer">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `iframe` instead of the `video` tag?

Comment: Could it be because the document loaded inside the iframe is overriding the cursor automatically? I wouldn't be too surprised if it worked that way.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. I don't know honestly. My friend gave me that code...trying to remember back, but we were trying to get a poster image to work with defer autoplay, + avoid the need to click twice to play. And settled on iframe. What should I change, can you help me?

Comment: Hi maco. All that's in the iframe is the video...

Answer (score 0):

```
.vidposter {cursor: pointer}
```

applying this css to container will mean a cursor will appear over the entire video content

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply...i tried that already and it didn't work. :( Do you think it's because it shows up as "element" due to the jquery? i also tried z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use a video element for more semantic html and better accessibility, like so

```
<div id="vidposter">
  <video aria-title="my poster" controls>
    <source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Try this for the jQuery part

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#vidposter').on('click', function() {
    $('#vidposter video source').attr('src', videoFile);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried all of these and none worked. :( I had tried some previously too. I really appreciate you replying though. I don't know why I can't get to the video. :/

Comment: I know you can do it, or sure why don't you video element or `<style></style>`

Comment: Hi binowhite. Thank you for replying. Can you show me what to change to try video? Just replace iframe with video code in the jquery? Or ?

Comment: I modified my previous answer

Comment: Hi bino. I'll try the new one because the first one didn't work. :x Thank you so much for coming back to update.